# UiView Gradient incorrectly positioned

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

II have a UIView within my viewController.  When i set a background colour to the view everything displays in the correct place.  But i am trying to add a gradient to the background of the UIView using

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.gradientView.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], color.CGColor, nil];
[self.gradientView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

The gradient displays nicely but not to the bounds of the UIView (it starts lower down the page than the UIView).  Any ideas?

Comment: I use this app to create my gradients, it outputs the code and you can manually set start and end points https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/gradient-creator/id1031070259?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

In gradient.colors array first object is always set as TopColor and second as a bottom color. May be your back ground color is white, so that is why it is not display as you want. Check out this below code:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = profileSection.bounds;
UIColor *colorTop = [UIColor greenColor];
UIColor *colorBot = [UIColor redColor];
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[colorTop CGColor], (id)[colorBot CGColor], nil];
gradient.masksToBounds = YES;
gradient.cornerRadius = 5;
[[profileSection layer] insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
profileSection.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.startPoint=CGPointMake(1, 0);
    gradient.frame = self.viewForSelectingLanguage.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.77f blue:0.635f alpha:1] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0.8f alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
    [self.viewForSelectingLanguage.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

In this code i have mentioned start point. you can mention start point.